# Import to blender removing faces

Tags: faces

When I import a model to blender that I produce myself (using either OBJ writing or FBX SDK) it seems to randomly delete faces.[image: faces]

I've checked for duplicate faces but there are zero here, and I'd presume blender wouldn't remove those anyway. What's up?

Comment: Duplicate/degenerate faces are removed (by [validate](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.91/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.validate)). You should post your obj/fbx file.

Comment: [Here's a different one](https://mega.nz/file/TthiRCDC#HQn6BLj86ibwAhAmhP-5Z0NJq_jtNbsHImvCuv3D5ig) that I still have, but it has the same problem.

Comment: That file has duplicate faces. Line 10205 and line 16866 are both "f 2904// 2911// 2905//".